# How To Set Up Subdomains Sites In GA4?

Tags: google-analytics

Previously, we could just create a single property, and create multiple views to see the data on each subdomain.
Now we don't have views anymore, and after a long search, I found no replacement.

Does that mean we have to create one property per subdomain, and have no way of seeing the combined data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a property for each subdomain, but a unique property, exactly as before, only instead of creating separate views you will have to create segments in the interface to isolate the information you need.

**UPDATE**
With GA4 360 you can separate data by subdomains or other criteria using subproperties: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11525732?hl=en